# C: How to check if free() has freed the memory?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function Free() in C doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774443/function-free-in-c-doesnt-work)

I just asked a question about free(), check the link below. If I can't use if(pointer != NULL), then what can I use, just in case it doesn't work because of a stupid mistake I made.

[Function free() in C isn't working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774443/function-free-in-c-doesnt-work)

Comment: Some of the answers to your other question did explain exactly why there's no way to do this check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you free a pointer you should set it to null - then you can use your test safetly

```
free(pointer);
pointer=NULL;

if(!pointer)
{
    pointer=malloc(42);
}
```

You could even create your own free function so you dont forget to set to null.

```
void myfree(void **ptr)
{
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr=NULL;
}
```

Comment: That's not completely safe, and some would argue that it's a crutch.  A contrived example: `p0 = malloc(42); p1 = p0; free(p0); p0 = NULL; /* p1 is now invalid */`.  More realistic examples are possible, but this comment is too small to contain them.

Comment: Agree its impossible to protect another programmer from themselves when using C :-)

Comment: I like to use the comma operator; `p=(free(p),NULL);`

Comment: `ptr = realloc(ptr,0);`
realloc returns a new pointer, or if the size is 0, then it returns NULL. If it has to shrink the allocated memory size, it also calls free() on on the unnecessary area.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use naked pointers.

Use `std::shared_ptr<OBJ>` and `std::unique_ptr<OBJ>`

Comment: There are no namespaces or templates in C

Comment: The question was marked as C++, I gave a C++ answer.  When people ask questions tagged both C++ and C, usually they mean just C++.  (Though I admit, the title should have tipped me off)

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think your logic is backwards.  A lot of the times (here anyway) they are really C questions.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I'd gotten the impression that they're new C++ coders who ask for a C answer because they know C answers also work, so they think the answers for the two languages will be the same.  Matter of perception maybe.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I guess it's just that you haven't been here for too long.  Give it some time, you'll see what I mean.  ;)

Comment: Looking at tags, Your C to C++ ratio is 8.7, while my C++ to C ratio is 12.8.  I'd guess perception.

Comment: @Mooing Duck, I'm going to have to side with Jeff Mercado on this one. The questions that are tagged both C and C++ are usually C questions. They usually come from newbie programmers who have not yet understood that the two languages are very different.